# Unify JSON files with jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm new in the community and I'm not a dev, but I have a task I need to find a solution for. I hope I can get your ideas.

I have a set of JSON files. I want to be able to use jq or a command line that can help me unify the files into one single file.

For example:

File 1, has the following format:

```
{
  "Interactions": [
    {
      "ID": "ispring://presentations/F7385CB7-DFDC-4D05-90FA-B927DB3D170D/quizzes/",
      "Type": "2",
      "TimestampUtc": "8/27/2020 12:09:54 PM",
      "Timestamp": "8/27/2020 12:09:54 PM",
      "Weighting": "",
      "Result": "1",
      "Latency": "1000",
      "Description": "What is the purpose of Summarizing next steps?\n\nSelect the correct box or boxes",
      "LearnerResponse": "0_correct_answer[,]1_Rectangle_2",
      "ScormActivityId": "12392705",
      "InteractionIndex": "3",
      "AULMRID": "38093846"
    },
  ]
}
```

File 2:

```
{
  "Interactions": [
    {
      "ID": "ispring://presentations/CAA34147-7B48-40C6-84FD-5CE8077DB2BF/quizzes/",
      "Type": "2",
      "TimestampUtc": "12/8/2020 6:19:12 PM",
      "Timestamp": "12/8/2020 6:19:12 PM",
      "Weighting": "",
      "Result": "1",
      "Latency": "1300",
      "Description": "'Can't do' language tends to relay this impression...\n\nSelect one.",
      "LearnerResponse": "4_All_of_the_above",
      "ScormActivityId": "13334358",
      "InteractionIndex": "3",
      "AULMRID": "40715598"
    },
  ]
}
```

And this is my expected result in a third file:

```
{
  "Interactions": [
    {
      "ID": "ispring://presentations/F7385CB7-DFDC-4D05-90FA-B927DB3D170D/quizzes/",
      "Type": "2",
      "TimestampUtc": "8/27/2020 12:09:54 PM",
      "Timestamp": "8/27/2020 12:09:54 PM",
      "Weighting": "",
      "Result": "1",
      "Latency": "1000",
      "Description": "What is the purpose of Summarizing next steps?\n\nSelect the correct box or boxes",
      "LearnerResponse": "0_correct_answer[,]1_Rectangle_2",
      "ScormActivityId": "12392705",
      "InteractionIndex": "3",
      "AULMRID": "38093846"
    },
   {
      "ID": "ispring://presentations/CAA34147-7B48-40C6-84FD-5CE8077DB2BF/quizzes/",
      "Type": "2",
      "TimestampUtc": "12/8/2020 6:19:12 PM",
      "Timestamp": "12/8/2020 6:19:12 PM",
      "Weighting": "",
      "Result": "1",
      "Latency": "1300",
      "Description": "'Can't do' language tends to relay this impression...\n\nSelect one.",
      "LearnerResponse": "4_All_of_the_above",
      "ScormActivityId": "13334358",
      "InteractionIndex": "3",
      "AULMRID": "40715598"
    },
  ]
}
```

Any ideas on how to unify them ?

Thank you!

RG

Comment: Note that neither of your documents is actually valid JSON so you should fix that before you proceed to jq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
jq -n '{ Interactions: [ inputs.Interactions ] | add }' file1.json file2.json
```

This assumes that you have made both input files valid JSON by stripping that trailing comma at the end of each object in the `Interactions` array.

For input file1.json:

```
{
  "Interactions": [
    {
      "ID": "file1",
      "Type": "1",
      "Timestamp": "8/27/2020 11:11:11 PM"
    }
  ]
}
```

and input file2.json:

```
{
  "Interactions": [
    {
      "ID": "file2",
      "Type": "2",
      "Timestamp": "8/27/2020 22:22:22 PM"
    }
  ]
}
```

this results in:

```
{
  "Interactions": [
    {
      "ID": "file1",
      "Type": "1",
      "Timestamp": "8/27/2020 11:11:11 PM"
    },
    {
      "ID": "file2",
      "Type": "2",
      "Timestamp": "8/27/2020 22:22:22 PM"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect after cleaning the commas. Thank you for pointing out the error with the commas and for the solution!